# PermissionError when using tikzplotlib

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, tikz, python-camelot

I'm investigating PDF-Files and I'm trying to display where text has been embedded as an image by the creators.

For this I'm using Camelot and it's Plot function. I then try to Plot this graph to Latex with TikZ.

However, sadly I recently had to switch operating Systems to Windows and now my I'm kinda lost. I'm getting the error "PermissionError" : [WinError32].

Ive closed all Cloud Solutions that might be synchronizing. I've also restartend the PC, then on the the first try I'm able to Extract Tables if I comment the rest of the code, but then I'm getting the error Message again.

```
import camelot
import tikzplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = "D:\example.pdf"
tables = camelot.read_pdf(path, pages = 2, flavor="stream")

camelot.plot(tables[0], kind="text")
tikzplotlib.save("D:\example.tex")
```

Comment: Is this a typo in your filename?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, there was one here. But've checked in spyder wheter the file actually exists or not and recived True.